# SQLite FTS necessary?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search

I am using Python with `sqlite3`.
Is there an advantage to using FTS3 or FTS4 if I only want to search for words in one column, or I could just use `LIKE "%word%"`?

Answer (score 1):

While yes, you could handle the simplest of cases with `LIKE '%word%'`, FTS allows user queries like `clown NOT circus` (matches rows talking about clowns but not circuses). It handles stemming (well, in English) so that `break` would match against `breaks` but not `breakdance`. It also builds indexes in a different way so that searching is much faster for this sort of query, and can return not just where the match happened but also a snippet of the matched text.

Finally, all the parsing of those potentially-complex user queries is done for you; that's code you don't have to write at all.